# Serving static files slow only for windows devices

Tags: apache, performance, nginx, static-files

We have some kind of strange behavior on our Openstack based servers. There is an nginx as loadbalancer with two apache web servers. This setup is automated by ansible and worked fine on our previous cloud.

After moving to another cloud we have the problem that all static files are served extremly slow. Slow means 35 seconds for a 140k JS file. And what makes it realy strange is that only windows devices have this problem.

When you download that static file on a Windows VM on a Mac it has the normal speed (100ms). Downloading it on a Linux VM on a Windows Host is very slow (35s). So it depends on the real system.

We have no idea where to start searching. Every tipp is welcome.

Comment: Did you check using something such as Chrome Dev Tools where the request time is going on both cases? Maybe this can bring some insight, but from my perspective seems more like a Windows configuration problem that something to do with the servers.

Comment: We checked with firebug and the time is going while transfering the file. 

The problem appears on all windows devices. So it´s not a specific configuration problem with a special testing system or so.

Comment: Strange, and aren't there any antivirus or analysis tools that might slow down? Could you tell us the Windows versions and browsers you're testing with? Just with what you wrote down is hard to say something

Comment: We have a lot of Windows versions and browsers in the office and the result is always the same. Windows7/8 + FireFox & Chrome [latest] in every combination. As the VM test shows, it doesn´t seem to be depending on the browser but more on the real host system.

Comment: Ah, sorry thought you meant you were seeking a server' problem. And IE doesn't reproduce the issue? DNS problems maybe?